# TypeScript: How to set type of destructured object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

**Problem**

For example, the parameter has the following type `{ component: any; element: ElementRef; }`, of which I only want the element:

```
onTextBoxInit({ element }) { }
```

**Question:** How can I set the type of this destructured element?

**Tried**

I thought of something like this: `onTextBoxInit({ element: ElementRef }) { }`, however this is not working.

Comment: The only option is to set the type of the parameter `onTextBoxInit({ element }: {element: ElementRef  })`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir oh lol thanks, that is the answer, please submit it :)

Comment: Why did I not thought of that :s

Comment: Submitted, from your question I thought it was what you were not looking for :-)

Comment: @Brampage - Sorry, I misread the code block because it has no context. That's a method declaration presumably within a `class`, so yeah, that's a parameter list and it's destructuring the parameter. :-) (I missed the `{}` at the end and it looked like a function *call*.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to specify the type of the argument after the destructuring expression

```
 onTextBoxInit({ element }: {element: ElementRef }){}
```

Comment: Setting the type of destructured object inside a destructured array: `([{todoId}, _]: [{todoId: string}, void]) => todoId` (e.g.: when using RxJS' combineLatest operator with params and some other subject).