# Typescript constructor shorthand when parameters are passed as an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I know we can make constructor short hand when we pass the parameters in a traditional way like

```
class Foo {
  
  private name: string;
  private age: number;

  constructor(name: string, age: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age= age;
  }
}
```

So the equivalent shorthand constructor notation for this class will be

```
class Foo {
      constructor(private name: string, private age: number) {}
    }
```

Similarly, how can I do the same shorthand when the constructor parameters are passed in as objects like below.

```
    class Foo {
      private name: string;
      private age: number;
      private group: string;
      constructor({
        name,
        age,
        group,
      }: {
        name: string;
        age: number;
        group: string;
      }) {
        this.name= name;
        this.age= age;
        this.group= group;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
  class Foo {
      constructor(public obj : { name: string, age: number, group: string}) {
      }
   }
  let foo = new Foo({name: 'name',  age: 42, group: 'answers'});

  alert(foo.obj.name);
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=24&pln=6&pc=2#code/ATDGBsEMGduAxA9o4BvAsAKBDsiB20ALgE4CuoRiJAFAA5kBG4AlqMIowFbABcawfJAC2AU37ESLfAHMANMEgzxgssMaiSCmSURk6E0tJkBfAJRosuECas2sd4OFFFgAM2TAAvINEB3BGQaVCExfgByUNFwhUVlfgAWACY5HT0DYHDIQj9NaHDzAG4HbBBIZxIiGg9EADpOLlqos0KgA)

Comment: I like this approach. Just out of curiosity, how I could access the members using this keyword inside the class. Is it possible with a similar approach? Something like this.name instead of this.obj.name

Comment: Yes you can. just like : `this.obj.age`

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi if you have a lot of properties in _obj_ you may use this shorthand to avoid type *this* everywhere: `const { prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4 } = this.obj`

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a shorter way. If you ignore the constructors and just try to assign that object to three variables `name`, `age`, and `group`, then this is really a question about how to declare types while destructuring an object:

```js
const { name, age, group } = {
  name: 'name',
  age: 42,
  group: 'answers',
};
```

TypeScript does not have a special notation for regular destructuring (lots of [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39672914/3960558) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51280924/3960558) and [blog](https://dev.to/spukas/typescript-object-destructuring-3n42) [posts](https://flaviocopes.com/typescript-object-destructuring/) end up using the same style as you did), so it does not have such a notation for destructuring inside a function definition.

You can keep the code a little cleaner by **making the type definition an interface**.